# GMap.NET explicit load cache?

Tags: gmap.net

How do I explicitly load the Data.gmdb cache file in GMap.NET? I tried copying over the file created on my machine to another machine and run the application in offline mode but the cache file (generated in PC1-Online) does not work for PC2-Offline. Is there a way to explicitly load the file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try to load your `your-cache-file.gmdb` into your application in this way:

In you `MainForm_Load` listener do the following:

```
 string pathToExecutable = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
 GMaps.Instance.ImportFromGMDB(pathToExecutable + "\your-cache-file.gmdb"); //or just whatever path to your cache
```

**Or** in this way:

```
YourGMapControl.CacheLocation = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

The last one creates `TileDBv5/en/Data.gmdb` in your executable directory folder, where cache to be replaced is located.

**But!** Don't forget about main things:

1. Gmap will make cache data in `MainMap.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerAndCache;` mode only. In `CacheOnly` it will use allready created cache, in `ServerOnly` it will load all the data from server without caching it locally.
2. In order to *force* caching process use `TilePrefetcher`. Example [here](https://github.com/radioman/greatmaps/blob/master/Demo.WindowsForms/Forms/MainForm.cs#L2042).

Answer (score 0):

at least after update to 2.1.7 CacheLocation only works if set in designer.vb

otherwise user/appdata/local folder is used